# [Pymysql]Failed to insert data，but don't have any error;

Tags: pymysql

```py
with DB.mysql() as cursor:
    res = cursor.execute(sql, args)

# DB.mysql() realize
try:
    conn = self.__pool.connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    yield cursor
    conn.commit()
except APIException as e:
    conn.rollback()
    raise e
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

note:
sql is a insert statement, res should be returned affected rows, but now res is zero, and don't have any error;

Comment: can you share the more code for understanding the context?

Comment: Do you ever commit the connection?

Comment: It's added. I left it out here